# Unexpected second listening port with .NET Remoting

Tags: .net, port, remoting, tcpchannel

We are big users of .NET Remoting, and have recently noticed that our server processes all have *two* active listening ports, appearing in netstat and Resource Monitor.  We are only registering *one* TcpChannel on a predefined port in our code, and can't work out what the second (apparently randomly allocated) listening port is.  Can anyone help and/or point to some technical documentation that covers this?  I've not been able to locate anything to date.

Many thanks.

Comment: TcpChannelListener can create both an IP4 and an IP6 socket at the same time.  It is unclear if that would be the case with this little info.  Why is this problem?  Take security worries to Microsoft Support.

Comment: I am happy to provide more info, if you can let me know what would be useful.  The reason it's a problem is that we need to explain to clients why our server processes are listening on two ports, when we expect them only to listen on the port we specify when configuring the TcpChannel.

Comment: Well, if you can't show a snippet or .config and don't want to use Support then just tell them that your app is ready for the day they'll switch to IP6.  Future-proof.  That ought to make them very happy.

Comment: There's no .NET config file.  The publish port and URI are read from a custom configuration file.  The Remoting server is set up as follows: `TcpServerChannel tcpChannel = new TcpServerChannel(publishPort);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, true);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(theInterface, uri, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);`  Looking at the Windows Resource Monitor, under Network|Listening Ports, I can see the server listening on the required port, but also on a second port with the address marked as "IPv4 unspecified".  So is the IPv6 thing relevant here?